# Java date Conversion issue having input date as String Oct 2014

Tags: java, date, java.util.date

I need to implement the logic whether input date such as SEP 2014, OCT 2014 , NOV 2014 etc is current month or not. I have written below logic for checking whether a selected week is a current week or not using below method but not able to implement for current month

```
public static boolean isCurrentWeek(Date date, Date dateStart, Date dateEnd)

 {

    if (date != null && dateStart != null && dateEnd != null) {


        if(date.equals(dateStart) || date.equals(dateEnd) ){


            return true;


        }else if (date.after(dateStart) && date.before(dateEnd)) {


            return true;


        }


        else {


            return false;

        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You have code for current week, and you're trying to figure out a current month version, what have you tried so far? Post *that* code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem with code similar to this one:

```
String target = "Oct 2000";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
try{
  Date date = df.parse(target);
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  Calendar targetCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  targetCalendar.setTime(date);
  System.out.println(targetCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
 } catch (ParseException e){
 }
```

String `target` is your input like "Sep 2014". This string is parsed to a `Date` and then used to set the time in a `Calendar` object. The second `Calendar` contains the current time.  The check if boths calenders match on their month is done is the `System.out.println` call.

Comment: Stefan, your code is checking only month but not year for e.g if i pass String target = "Oct 2000" and current month is OCT 2014 its will return true. It should compare the year as well

Comment: I have modified the your as below and its working fine  public static boolean isCurrentMonth(String dateStart) throws ParseException{
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
  Date date = df.parse(dateStart);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar targetCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    targetCalendar.setTime(date);
    
    return (targetCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) && targetCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
 }

Comment: In your question you are asking only for a match on the month (you wrote: "is current month or not."). As you already know, the code can be easily extended to check also for the year :) So, I you think this solutions works for you, please vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

Try Apache Commons for this:

```
DateUtils.truncatedEquals( date, new Date(), Calendar.MONTH );
```

It returns `true` if the two date is in the same month.

**EDIT**

Maybe this:

```
public static boolean isInCurrentMonth(String inputDateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        Date inputDate = sdf.parse(inputDateString);
        return DateUtils.truncatedEquals(new Date(), inputDate, Calendar.MONTH);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: I have two date on my calender, startDate="OCT 2014" and end Date is also the same, so i am getting this value in String but not able to figure it out how to to get First day and last of the month selected

Comment: Basicaly i need to check whether today date is in between the start date and end date of a month. but as i am getting a string OCT 2014 as start Date and End date i am not able to parse it to date format